# SharePoint calendar entries not viewable from outlook desktop

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-calendar

I have a weird issue, since Office 365 limits the calendar threshold to 5000 items, adding the calendar to SharePoint does not show any entries while seeing from outlook.

I spoke Microsoft and they are saying that,  the only solution for this issue in 365 is bringing the limit down to 5000 or less items for a calendar.

I was wondering if someone has come across this issue and found a solution, maybe some kind of third party tool, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using connect to outlook to sync calendar with outlook?

The threshold of the lists (including calendars) is 5000 currently. Once the limit is exceeded, it seems that there's nothing you can do with the list.

Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Or you can submit a feedback about this issue via the below link for your convenience.

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks Lisa, Yes I am using Connect to outlook for syncing. That's what I got to know from 365 support. This is a serious problem for the client as they want to leverage add/update calendar items from outlook itself. Is there a work around for it or no at this point?